# What to write under if __name__ == "__main__": if the entire .py file is a module and will never run as its own script?

Tags: python

I don't understand the importance of having

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

in my .py files. But I don't know what to place under it if the functions I want to exist in the module are all I want in the file. In other words, the module .py file will never run on its own.

```
def my_function():
    do_stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ???
```

Do I place the function definitions  here again along with necessary modules?

Comment: Just don't use the if block at all, it's not mandatory.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the importance of the block then. If I leave it out won't it run the whole .py file as soon as it's imported to my main .py script instead of just giving me access to its functions?

Comment: It runs the whole .py file either way. That block isn't anything special according to the compiler; it's just an if statement that we happen to use a lot.

Comment: Isn't running the whole file on import _the whole point_ of importing Python files?

Comment: From another angle; if you have code that you don't want to be executed when the file is being imported into another module, put it under `if __name__ == '__main__'`. If you have no such code, there is no need to use `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: @ForceBru He probably somehow called the functions (inside the module) declared in the module, thus executing them during import

Comment: I see now. If all I have are definitions of functions nothing will really run anyway so the block isn't necessary. It will just make the functions available. If I needed to control entry point then I'd worry about it. Ok I don't know why it wasn't clicking. Thanks.

Comment: Think of it this way: running a `def` statement *creates* a function without calling into it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't uncommon to see people put tests there, as sort of a light-weight, poor man's testing framework.

As has been said in the comments it is optional.

`__name__` will be equal to the module name when run as a module.